# Can I use a wildcard certificate for some subdomains and not others?

Tags: ssl-certificate, subdomain

I have a VPS environment with 4 IPs, 3 of which of which point to 1 or more subdomains. The other is the TLD. Because of the use of host headers, subdomains have needed to be isolated on their own IP to get a cert.

If I purchased a wildcard cert for a single IP with N subdomains, would this cause any issue with the following:

1. The main TLD, which has it's own cert
2. The single IP, single subdomain instances that have their own cert

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do this!  Certificates you don't present and that aren't in the chain to the local trust root on the client don't have any effect on the process.

As long as you make sure the listener on each IP is presenting a certificate that is valid for all the domains it hosts, you'll be fine.